# wp comment author dont refere to author page

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, author

I want to link the author name shown in comments to the author page. 
for ex:

> bla bla bla written by **user**.

if I clicked the author link I want to go to `../author/user/` page.

my code is:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/author/<?php comment_author($comment); ?>"><?php comment_author($comment); ?></a>
```

it shows the author's first and last name/display name. but I want to show nickname. 
If I clicked the author name the output is:

```
../author/user%20user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?>
```

Remove your a tag and place above function.

For more info. Please refer link : [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_link)

Hope this works for you.